# Terraform: How to copy files from s3 to ec2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data, terraform0.12+

I have a terraform configuration that creates an `autoscaling group` and a `launch configuration` as well as an `s3 bucket` and populates the bucket with a number of files.

Is there a way to copy the files from the `s3 bucket` to the `ec2 instance`, considering that the `s3 bucket` name won't be known till after creation?

The `ec2 instance` has an `iam profile` with the right permissions. My stumbling block is the bucket name not being known till creation time so I'm not sure if I accomplish this via `user_data`

Answer (score 1):

You can try specify bucket resource in `depends_on` in `aws_instance` resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ...
  user_data = <<-EOT
    BUCKET_URL=${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_domain_name}
    s3 cp s3://$BUCKET_NAME/ ./ --recursive
  EOT
}
```

Hit me if I wrong, but I think that [this link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file#example-usage) will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

your terraform script should be something like this

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "myBucket" {
  bucket = "${var.my_bucket_name}"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/user_data.sh")}"

  vars = {
      aws_s3_bucket = "${var.my_bucket_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch" {
  name_prefix          = "my-launch-config"
  image_id             = "${var.aws_ami}"
  instance_type        = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups      = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  user_data            = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.name}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_s3_bucket.myBucket"]
}

==========================

templates/user_data.sh

==========================

#!/bin/bash

s3 cp s3://${aws_s3_bucket}/ ./ --recursive
```